# Generate wikibase ontology endpoint from local wikibase

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I set up my own wikibase and it is running. I'm also able to use sparql but the `wikibase PREFIX` is not working

`PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>`

In my query UI, I need to use it like

`PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology-beta#>`

but this would break the query such as

```
?p wikibase:claim ?t
```

The question is can I generate the wikibase based on my own database? Is there other alternatives?

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? Show us your query, show us your results, tell us what is different from what you want/expect. My best immediate guess is that you should use something like `PREFIX wikibase-beta: <http://wikiba.se/ontology-beta#>` but that's based on very little in your question!

Comment: @TallTed I guess, somewhere in the setup scripts of Wikidata RDF dump, the `wikibase` namespace is currently configured as `http://wikiba.se/ontology-beta#` compared to what is used in the public Wikidata online available via SPARQL. I'm pretty sure there is some option somewhere, the Wikidata guys should know better though. Indeed, I don't know which instructions the TO used, maybe this [guide](https://github.com/wikimedia/wikidata-query-rdf/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) ? Maybe also an older dataset has been loaded, don't know.

Comment: The Wikibase code was recently updated to migrate away from -beta.
https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/mediawiki/extensions/Wikibase/+/269357/
if you update your Wikibase you might find this all just works.